# Flutter Run command is not working - how to fix the following error?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

'flutter run' command is crashing. All of a sudden it has started throwing the following error.

```
flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software
rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.8s
Resolving dependencies...                                           9.3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         8.2s
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
cmd: Can't find service: activity
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                         0.5s
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\www\flutter\helloworld\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: cmd: Can't find service: package
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.
```

I've tried to run 'flutter doctor' and I don't see any issue there.

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.557], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.35.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to run the app on an emulator? if you are, try to run on a real device. or try wiping or recreating the emulator. that might help.

Comment: Am facing the issue in the emulator, and wiping the data is solving the issue. Since am facing this very frequently, so am looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: you can use another version of android on your emulator, that might solve the issue. But i always recommend to use a real device. You will get more out of a real device than the emulator. You can also run flutter run --profile on a real device to see how the app will perform. for reference : https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/ui-performance

Comment: This issue is found only if the device(real device) is connected. And the button will be in green colour if the device is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had similar issue, but I think it’s some kind of AVD problem there. I solved it creating new device, but had a lot of OSX (I’m still wondering how this is even posible) crashes until I stumble with the right one, that’s why I think there’s some kind of incompatibility between the hardware and the device it’s trying to emulate.
tl;dr try changing the virtual device with another one.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue when using the real device to test.there was a setting which allow to install aps via usb and i had to enable it manually.that fixed my problem